# Trying to recursively add the square of numbers

Tags: python

```
def recursive_add(s):
    sum = 0
    if len(s) == 1:
        sum += s[0] ** 2
    else:
        recursive_add(s[1:])
        sum += s[0]**2
    return sum


s = [8, 6, 8, 4]

print recursive_add(s)
```

however, for some reason, 8 gets squared right away and 64 is returned, even though it should be the last number to be squared and added to sum.

Comment: You throw away the result of the recursive call to `recursive_add`. I bet this is not what you intended to do.

Comment: this has homework written all over it

Comment: actually it's not homework...i'm just working ahead since we're going to need it for the final next month

Comment: You say that "8 gets squared right away and 64 is returned".  Actually, that's not what happens.  Since you don't know what happens, I suggest you add `print` statements to find out.  Since comment boxes don't work well for code, I'll post an answer with example code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def recursive_add(s):
    if s:
        return s[0]**2 + recursive_add(s[1:])
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: My favorite answer so far.  It is self-contained with no need for an external global, and the way it breaks down the list and adds as it goes is very clear.

Answer (score 3):

First, an one-liner solution for your specific problem:

```
def rec_add(s):
    return s[0] * s[0] + rec_add(s[1:]) if s else 0
```

More advanced and abstract stuff follows.

In functional programming jargon, you "map" x**2 on a list and "fold" the list by adding its elements together. Python provides necessary primitives for that (`map` and `reduce` respectively) and the sum of squares can be simply written as:

```
from operator import add, mul

xs = [1,2,3,5]
print reduce(add, map(mul, xs, xs)) # 39
```

You can also combine map and fold steps in one function:

```
def map_and_fold(xs, mapfun, foldfun, init):
    if not xs:
        return init
    return foldfun(
        mapfun(xs[0]),
        map_and_fold(
            xs[1:], mapfun, foldfun, init))
```

and define `sum_squares` as a partial application of the above:

```
from functools import partial

sum_squares = partial(map_and_fold, 
    mapfun = lambda x: x * x,
    foldfun = lambda x, y: x + y,
    init = 0)
```

Test:

```
xs = [1,2,3,5]
print sum_squares(xs) # 39
```

More info: [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29), [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29), [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

Comment: In case you decide to go with reduce and map :
list_add_squares = lambda list : reduce(add, map(mul, list, list))

Comment: I like the idea of doing `from operator import mul` `sum(map(mul,s,s))`

Comment: @jamylak: well, in real-life python `sum(x * x for x in xs)` would be fine, but the point of my answer was to explain some functional programming concepts.

Comment: a groundberaking definition of "one-liner"

Answer (score 2):

You can just:

```
def recursive_add(s):
    return s and (recursive_add(s[1:]) + s[0]**2) or 0
```

In your original code, the issue seems to be that `recursive_add(s[1:])` doesn't share the same `sum` with `recursive_add(s)`. The `sum`s are different ones. Try this instead:

```
sum = 0

def recursive_add(s):
    global sum
    if len(s) == 1:
        sum += s[0] ** 2
    else:
        recursive_add(s[1:])
        sum += s[0]**2

s = [8, 6, 8, 4]

print recursive_add(s)
```

Comment: Don't use `and` / `or`, Python has a real conditional expression / ternary operation. `recursive_add(s[1:]) + s[0]**2 if s else 0`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to figure out why your program isn't working correctly, it is good to figure out exactly what it *is* doing.  Here is an example of how to modify your program to show what it's really doing.

```
def recursive_add(s):
    print "DEBUG: recursive_add(%s)" % repr(s)
    sum = 0
    print "DEBUG: sum: %d" % sum
    if len(s) == 1:
        sum += s[0] ** 2
        print "DEBUG: sum: %d" % sum
    else:
        recursive_add(s[1:])
        sum += s[0]**2
        print "DEBUG: sum: %d" % sum
    return sum


s = [8, 6, 8, 4]

print "result: %d" % recursive_add(s)
```

When you run this, here is what you get:

```
DEBUG: recursive_add([8, 6, 8, 4])
DEBUG: sum: 0
DEBUG: recursive_add([6, 8, 4])
DEBUG: sum: 0
DEBUG: recursive_add([8, 4])
DEBUG: sum: 0
DEBUG: recursive_add([4])
DEBUG: sum: 0
DEBUG: sum: 16
DEBUG: sum: 64
DEBUG: sum: 36
DEBUG: sum: 64
result: 64
```

As you can see, your function does successfully snip the first number off the list, and calls itself recursively until it has handled all the numbers.  But the problem is that you keep re-setting sum to 0, so sum isn't accumulating an actual sum; so your final answer is 0 + 64, or just 64.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was quite simple just add the recursive-add(s[1:]) to sum in else part:

```
def recursive_add(s):
    sum = 0
    if len(s) == 1:
        sum += int(s[0]) ** 2
    else:
        sum = sum+int(s[0])**2+recursive_add(s[1:])
    return sum
s = [8, 6, 8, 4]
print (recursive_add(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not what you want.
In very first place, declare `sum = 0` into `recursive_add` will lead to a different behaviour respect of that you expected.

I suggest to modify it in

```
def recursive_add(s,sum):
 if len(s) == 1:
  return sum + s[0] ** 2
 else:
  sum = s[0] ** 2 + recursive_add(s[1:],sum)
 return sum
```

And call it in that way

```
s = [8, 6, 8, 4]
print recursive_add(s,0)
```